# How to get JSON serialized string using Dart Serialization

Tags: json, serialization, dart

For the following code

```
var address = new Address();
address.street = 'N 34th';
address.city = 'Seattle';
var serialization = new Serialization()
 ..addRuleFor(address);
String output = serialization.write(address);
```

How do i get a json output like this:

```
address: {'street':'N 34th', 'city':'Seattle'}
```

Output generated by above code is as follows:

```
{"roots":[{"__Ref":true,"rule":3,"object":0}],"data":[[],[],[],[["Seattle","N 34th"]]],"rules":"{\"roots\":[{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":1,\"object\":0}],\"data\":[[],[[{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":4,\"object\":0},{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":3,\"object\":0},{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":5,\"object\":0},{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":6,\"object\":0}]],[[],[],[\"city\",\"street\"]],[[]],[[]],[[]],[[{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":2,\"object\":0},{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":2,\"object\":1},\"\",{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":2,\"object\":2},{\"__Ref\":true,\"rule\":7,\"object\":0}]],[\"Address\"]],\"rules\":null}"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [JsonObject for Dart](https://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject), add this to your `pubspec.yaml` file and then run `pub install` (Tools -> Pub Install)

```
dependencies:
  json_object: 
    git: git://github.com/chrisbu/dartwatch-JsonObject.git
```

And then change your code to call `objectToJson` :

```dart
import 'package:json_object/json_object.dart';

var address = new Address();
address.street = 'N 34th';
address.city = 'Seattle';
String output =  objectToJson(address);
```

Note that `objectToJson` requires mirrors support (the reflection capabilities) which only work in Dart VM at the moment. It does not work in dart2js as of 2012-12-20.

Answer (score 12):

It turns out that the `dart:json` library makes this very easy. You need to implement `toJson` in your class to make it work.

For example:

```
class Address {
  String street;
  String city;

  Map toJson() {
    return {"street": street, "city": city};
  }
}

main() {
  var addr = new Address();
  addr.street = 'N 34th';
  addr.city = 'Seattle';
  print(JSON.stringify(addr));
}
```

Which will print out:

```
{"street":"N 34th","city":"Seattle"}
```

Comment: Hey Seth, I don't understand, will `JSON.stringfy` look for a  `Map.toJson()` method in your object?

Comment: JSON.stringify will call toJson() on your object, and toJson() must return something JSON knows how to encode natively, like an int, string, bool, map, list, etc.

Comment: @SethLadd How it works with Array/List? Suppose I have this member  List<Coordinate> Coordinates; inside address class, How should I write toJson

Comment: @SutikshanDubey can you please ask this question as its own stackoverflow question? It deserves a formal answer. :) thanks!

Comment: @SethLadd Thanks :) here I posted my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22650276/dart-how-to-get-json-object-from-complex-object-hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the dart:json package rather than serialization. The output from the serialization is JSON, but it's JSON of the serialized structures and it's worrying about things like handling cycles that are overkill for what you're looking at. With the basic json package you can implement a toJson() method that will do the transformation and basic system objects are handled automatically. That has the advantage of not requiring mirrors, so it will work on the current dartj2s. Or you can use json_object as in the previous answer.